# Find complex number representing circumcentre and orthocentre of a triangle with vertices represented by complex number z1, z2, z3?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am having hard time finding it, the method for finding orthocentre and circumcentre we use in coordinate geometry won't work here if complex number are not given in form of a+ib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R_C$ be the circumradius and $z$ be the complex number representing the circumcentre then we have the condition:
$$|z - z_1| = |z - z_2| = |z - z_3| = R_C$$
Again, if $z'$ be the orthocentre then it satisfies the condition:
$$Re(\frac {z' - z_1}{z_2 - z_3}) = Re(\frac {z' - z_2}{z_3 - z_1}) = Re(\frac {z' - z_3}{z_1 - z_2}) = 0$$
I hope it helps.

Comment: The equation you had written does not represent a formula it is more like a relation. I am looking for a direct formula for circumcentre and orthocentre which will give you the complex number representing that point in argand plane.